# Flexslider thumbnails below slider in SHOPIFY pages (not product images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, thumbnails, shopify, flexslider

I've dug and dug and tried to make sense of some of the previous questions, forgive me in advance, java and jquery are not my specialty. I would love a hand in how to organize and invoke a working slider with thumbnails that link properly below it using flexslider.(It's for a slide-show with clickable thumbnails)

Can anyone tell me what should be uploaded where and invoked where?

I have uploaded in my assets: **flexslider.css**, **jquery.flexslider-min.js** (which i think comes with my specific theme "minimal"), **jquery.flexslider.js**

I don't know what to include in my "PAGE"S' HTML, and wether to make a separate template for my pages with any code. I'm also unclear on if I need to modify anything in theme.liquid or if anything in the css needs to be changed.

Any advice would be very much appreciated. I will keep digging the forums.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Flexslider has some specific HTML that is required to generate the slideshow. I would create an alternate page template e.g. page.slider.liquid and place that in there. In your theme.liquid file -- underneath where jQuery is included -- you can do this:

```
{% if template == 'page.slider' %}

  // include your flexslider css and js refs

{% endif %}
```